# Android sound problem

Tags: android, media-player

In my app when user clicks a button, a sound is played. Since the user can push that button many times and much faster than the length of the sound, i shortened the sound. Now it's like 0.2 sec or sg. Strange is, now Android cannot play the sound, my app force closes. So is it the length of the sound or what? It is a similar .mp3 than the one before.
This is the code i am using:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(Start.this, R.raw.clicksound2);   
                mp.start();
                NameButton.setEnabled(false);
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                        mp.release();
                        NameButton.setEnabled(true);
                    }

                });
```

Logcat:

```
06-09 05:38:23.774: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-09 05:38:23.774: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at com.bfarago.clickme.Start$1.onClick(Start.java:113)
06-09 05:38:23.774: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
06-09 05:38:23.774: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
06-09 05:38:23.774: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-09 05:38:23.774: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-09 05:38:23.774: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-09 05:38:23.774: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-09 05:38:23.774: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 05:38:23.774: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-09 05:38:23.774: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-09 05:38:23.774: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-09 05:38:23.774: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-09 05:38:23.794: WARN/ActivityManager(70):   Force finishing activity com.bfarago.clickme/.Start
06-09 05:38:24.357: WARN/ActivityManager(70): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{43efc7b0 com.bfarago.clickme/.Start}
```

Line 113 is the `mp.start();`

Comment: try to give geBaseContext() in place of Start.this

Comment: I shortened another file and i get the same error. I am using Audacity for this. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the rest of your code but in your code you have mp.release() called when
MediaPlayer mp finished playing and after that the object mp is no longer available so you need to create it again.

Comment: I play two sounds. The first one is played, the second one is not. The second one is created from the first one by shortening. There is nothing wrong with the code.